# Mongodb Find Query on large dataset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having issue in fetching data from mongodb. Db is having 50k+ data right now.
when i execute query on mongo shell, result is returned within 2 seconds. But when i fetch data from nodejs it takes around 15+ seconds.

I have tried using indexes but no use it.

var arr = [...commonSearch.$and,...searchQuery.$and]; // total there are 9 conditions

let totalRecord = await testModel.find( {$and : arr},      {dcn:1}   );

System detail:
nodejs v8.2.0
mongo v4.2.2
mongoose v4.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Create the index with respective to the fields which you are using in query.

Ex:

```
{
"name":"John",
"dob":"18/12/1989",
"country":"India",
...
}
{
"name":"David",
"dob":"26/19/1981",
"country":"China",
...
}
```

If you are querying on name and country add a index as below

```
db.myColl.createIndex({name:1, country:1})
```

Comment: @ROHITW I have faced the same scenario previously. Here there are 50K+, But we have 2M+ records, we have added the index, the issue resolved.  Here the fetching time from database will be reduced by adding the index.